# how do I get a list of amplitudes from a audio file?

Tags: linux, audio, wav, amplitude

how do I get a list of amplitudes from a audio file using a linux command line tool ?

Comment: something like http://linux.die.net/man/1/harminv ?

Comment: Looks like it might help, but according to the harmniv doc, it requires an input. What input must I provide ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I decode a RAW/WAV file into a list of numbers ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482221/how-can-i-decode-a-raw-wav-file-into-a-list-of-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean getting all the individual samples as text?  [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can do that.

```
$ sox file.wav file.dat
```

will take an audio file `file.wav`, and generate a text file `file.dat` with a column for the timebase in seconds, and a column for each audio channel scaled by the maximum possible value.

Comment: I wanted to know what is the value for each time of each channel ? Is it a frequency or is it an amplitude ?

Comment: So would it be right to plot a sound waveform (e.g the one in http://soundcloud.com/dawnbrian5/photograph-katie-by-brian-clayton) using the values from the .dat file ?

Comment: Also, why does it lie between a range of -1 to +1 ? (according to SoX docs) ?

Comment: 1. Yes, you can plot the sound waveform with those vales. 2. Because the samples are scaled by their maximum possible value.  In the case of 16-bit samples, that would be 2^15, in the case of 24-bit samples, 2^23.

Comment: Ah thanks. Make more sense now.